# How to use more than 1 metadata tag in search criteria of "Items matching a tag" webpart

Tags: web-part, search-results

I would like the webpart to display pages with 2 metadata tags, but right now it only allows me to input 1 tag ("1.Executive Summary").

I have tried to include the second tag ("Product") in the "Add additional filters" box, but the results are not accurate.

[image]

Under refiners, I am able to select a second tag too add, but it does not work as well. It does not work like an additional filter, and I'm not too sure what it actually does.

Please assist!

Comment: Are you looking for result "tag A and tag B" or "tag A or tag B"?

Comment: @MarkL "tag A and tag B" thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you switch advanced mode you can build your query the way you want it, and aren't limited to one or two tags. You can match five tags if it suites your need. Take a look at the Query text at the bottom of the following image. That's where you build your query.

[image]

You find the setting to advanced mode on the BASIC tab:

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you, this looks like it might work, but how do I access the advanced mode? The option does not seem to be available to me :/

Comment: @MelissaLim You should see it on the BASIC tab. If not, which subscription do you use?

Comment: Nope, I don't see it on the BASIC tab. Could this be linked to the permission level? I'm using O365 sharepoint online.

Comment: @MelissaLim Have you enabled Enterprise Features in your site collection? With subscription plan I mean Enterprise E1 or E3. You need an E3 at least. You see the subscription in the Admin Center. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office-365-plan-options.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Before searching you should create managed property in admin of that metadata and then you can search it.
after that you search like this 
for Ex: ColumnName:"ItemName" AND ColumnName1:"ItemName"
Column Name is the managed property which is created by you.
hope this information will help you.